# Is there a loss function that measures the cross similarity between two 2D tensors?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, loss-function, pytorch, similarity

Given two input tensors `x1` and `x2` with the shape `[batch_size, hidden_size]`, let `S` be the matrix of similarity between all pairs `(predict, target)`, where `predict` and `target` are dense vectors with the shape `[hidden_size]` and `predict` belongs to `x1` and `target` belongs to `x2`.

[image]

Is there any loss function that is minimized as the values in the diagonal of `S` are close to `1` while the other values are close to `-1`?

That is, the similarity between the vectors from `x1` and `x2` of the same index must be greater than between vectors of different indexes.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I've implemented the following solution inpired by [N-Pair Loss published from NIPS 2016](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/6200-improved-deep-metric-learning-with-multi-class-n-pair-loss-objective):

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn


class NPairsLoss(nn.Module):
    """
    The N-Pairs Loss.
    It measures the loss given predicted tensors x1, x2 both with shape [batch_size, hidden_size],
    and target tensor y which is the identity matrix with shape  [batch_size, batch_size].
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super(NPairsLoss, self).__init__()
        self.ce = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    def show(self, similarity_scores):
        sn.heatmap(similarity_scores.detach().numpy(), annot=True, annot_kws={'size': 7}, vmin=-1.0, vmax=1.0)
        plt.show()

    def similarities(self, x1, x2):
        """
        Calculates the cosine similarity matrix for every pair (i, j),
        where i is an embedding from x1 and j is another embedding from x2.

        :param x1: a tensors with shape [batch_size, hidden_size].
        :param x2: a tensors with shape [batch_size, hidden_size].
        :return: the cosine similarity matrix with shape [batch_size, batch_size].
        """
        x1 = x1 / torch.norm(x1, dim=1, keepdim=True)
        x2 = x2 / torch.norm(x2, p=2, dim=1, keepdim=True)
        return torch.matmul(x1, x2.t())

    def forward(self, predict, target):
        """
        Computes the N-Pairs Loss between the target and predictions.
        :param predict: the prediction of the model,
        Contains the batches x1 (image embeddings) and x2 (description embeddings).
        :param target: the identity matrix with shape  [batch_size, batch_size].
        :return: N-Pairs Loss value.
        """
        x1, x2 = predict
        predict = self.similarities(x1, x2)
        self.show(predict)
        # by construction the probability distribution must be concentrated on the diagonal of the similarities matrix.
        # so, Cross Entropy can be used to measure the loss.
        return self.ce(predict, target)
```

However, with this loss, the model ends up converging to a scenario where all dense vectors are equal to each other. Which can be seen by executing the following code snippet:

```py
batch_size=7
hidden_size=768
def m_model(scenario=0):
    if scenario == 0: # all equal all
        p1 = torch.ones((batch_size, hidden_size)) 
        p2 = p1
    elif scenario == 1: # all different all
        p1 = torch.ones((batch_size, hidden_size))
        p2 = -1*p1
    else: # desired case
        p1 = torch.rand((batch_size, hidden_size))
        p2=p1

    return p1, p2

predict = m_model(scenario=0)
target = torch.arange(batch_size)
loss = NPairsLoss(1)

print("Loss:", loss(predict, target))
# Loss: tensor(1.9459), using scenario=0
# Loss: tensor(1.9459), using scenario=1
# Loss: tensor(1.7364), using scenario=2
```

Any suggestions on how to penalize these scenarios where the similarity matrix has all the same values?

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is good, and it seems like you are computing pairwise cosine similarity, if it is the case, it's better to use : F.normalise instead of dividing directly with norm.

The full answer is :

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class NPairsLoss(nn.Module):
    """
    The N-Pairs Loss.
    It measures the loss given predicted tensors x1, x2 both with shape [batch_size, hidden_size],
    and target tensor y which is the identity matrix with shape  [batch_size, batch_size].
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super(NPairsLoss, self).__init__()
        self.ce = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    def show(self, similarity_scores):
        sn.heatmap(similarity_scores.detach().numpy(), annot=True, annot_kws={'size': 7}, vmin=-1.0, vmax=1.0)
        plt.show()

    def similarities(self, x1, x2):
        """
        Calculates the cosine similarity matrix for every pair (i, j),
        where i is an embedding from x1 and j is another embedding from x2.

        :param x1: a tensors with shape [batch_size, hidden_size].
        :param x2: a tensors with shape [batch_size, hidden_size].
        :return: the cosine similarity matrix with shape [batch_size, batch_size].
        """
        x1 = F.normalise(x1, dim=1)
        x2 = F.normalise(x2, dim=1)
        return torch.matmul(x1, x2.t())

    def forward(self, predict, target):
        """
        Computes the N-Pairs Loss between the target and predictions.
        :param predict: the prediction of the model,
        Contains the batches x1 (image embeddings) and x2 (description embeddings).
        :param target: the identity matrix with shape  [batch_size, batch_size].
        :return: N-Pairs Loss value.
        """
        x1, x2 = predict
        predict = self.similarities(x1, x2)
        self.show(predict)
        # by construction the probability distribution must be concentrated on the diagonal of the similarities matrix.
        # so, Cross Entropy can be used to measure the loss.
        return self.ce(predict, target)
```

Another way to do this is by using correlation matrix instead of cosine (from Barlow Twins Loss Function) :

````
import torch
import torch.distributed as dist


def correlation_loss_func(
    z1: torch.Tensor, z2: torch.Tensor, lamb: float = 5e-3, scale_loss: float = 0.025
) -> torch.Tensor:
    """Computes Correlation loss given batch of projected features z1 from view 1 and
    projected features z2 from view 2.

    Args:
        z1 (torch.Tensor): NxD Tensor containing projected features from view 1.
        z2 (torch.Tensor): NxD Tensor containing projected features from view 2.
        lamb (float, optional): off-diagonal scaling factor for the cross-covariance matrix.
            Defaults to 5e-3.
        scale_loss (float, optional): final scaling factor of the loss. Defaults to 0.025.

    Returns:
        torch.Tensor: Correlation Loss.
    """

    N, D = z1.size()

    # to match the original code
    bn = torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(N, affine=False).to(z1.device)
    z1 = bn(z1.T).T
    z2 = bn(z2.T).T

    corr = (z1 @ z2.T) / N

    if dist.is_available() and dist.is_initialized():
        dist.all_reduce(corr)
        world_size = dist.get_world_size()
        corr /= world_size

    diag = torch.eye(N, device=corr.device) # if you want invariance between views
    cdif = (corr - diag).pow(2)
    cdif[~diag.bool()] *= lamb
    loss = scale_loss * cdif.sum()
    return loss
```
````